# submitting to arxiv with garamond

Tags: fonts, mathdesign, arxiv

When I read this http://arxiv.org/help/faq/freefonts
I assumed I could just use the mathdesign package with the urw-garamond option and it would work.

Unfortunately this is not the case - silly me.
Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Reading that page the answer is no. In order to use URW Garamond with TeX Live you have to install it with `getnonfreefonts`: it has a non-free license, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Reading the page you refer to, the answer is no. The URW Garamond font *can* be installed in TeX Live, but only with the `getnonfreefonts` tool, as it has a non-free license (although it call itself "free").

> ### License
>
> Distribution and modification of the the URW Garamond fonts
>   are subject to the Aladdin Free Public License
>   http://www.artifex.com/downloads/doc/Public.htm
>
> Copyright (c) 2000 by (URW)++ Design & Development
>
> The font GaramondNo8 Italic has been modified, as compared
>   with the version from the original distribution site
>   http://www.artifex.com/downloads/; credits to Ralf Stubner
>   for fixing the broken quotedblleft character.

For the license itself, see http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/6.01/Public.htm